# TypeError: - is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, function, console

I have this `form` which should hide another form:

```html
  <!--checkbox-->
  <form method="POST" action="start.inc.php">
      <span id="switch"><!--these are for css, the input matters-->
          <label>
              <input id="hide" name="hide" type="checkbox" onclick="hide()" /><!--error here-->
              <span class="slider"></span>
          </label>
          <label for="hide">Do not set a password</label>
      </span>
  </form>

  <!--this should be hidden-->
  <form method="POST" action="start.inc.php">
      <!--form stuff-->
    <button type="submit" name="check">Set Password</button>
  </form>
```

So I implemented a function like this:

```js
function hide() {
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("hide");
    var form =  document.getElementsByTagName("form")[1];

    if (checkBox.checked == true)
    {
        form.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        form.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

It is written *before* the html, but even changing their order nothing changes...

The problem is that when I click on the checkbox the form doesn't disappear and I get the following error on the console:
`(index):93 Uncaught TypeError: hide is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick`

Note: I'm a beginner in JS so please don't flame me if it was a stupid error

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the name of the function is the same as the ID of the element. Element IDs become global variables, so `hide` is the `<input>` element rather than the function. The key to realizing this is that the error message doesn't say that `hide` is undefined, it says that it's not a function -- that means it's something else (in this case, a DOM element).

Give the function a name that's not the same as any element ID and it will work.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)